# error while executing python scripts with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed python, pip and selenium in my system and I'm testing a sample code on basic sites.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\skandregula\\PycharmProjects\\sele\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

> ```
> error:C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:/Users/skandregula/PycharmProjects/sele/script.py Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/skandregula/PycharmProjects/sele/script.py", line 5, in
> <module>
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\skandregula\\PycharmProjects\\sele\\geckodriver.exe")
> File
> "C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 81, in __init__
>     desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 157, in __init__
>     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 252, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\skandregula\PycharmProjects\sele\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable
> to find a matching set of capabilities
> ```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" despite driver being in /usr/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713445/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in)

Comment: Try passing the path in the keyword argument `executable_path`

Comment: i did use executable_path, but the error is at webdriver

Comment: how can install webdriver

Comment: selenium is installed

Comment: webdriver is not installled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Selenium WebDriver python bindings in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-selenium-webdriver-python-bindings-in-chrome)

Comment: You are passing geckodriver for stating the chrome? download chrome driver.Check the link above.  Also this basic example http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\skandregula\\PycharmProjects\\sele\\geckodriver.exe")
```

this line is attempting to launch an instance of a Chrome browser, but you are passing it the path to `geckodriver.exe`, which is the Webdriver for Firefox.  You need to use `chromedriver.exe` for Chrome.