# How to send username and password in popup box through selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, popupwindow

Click the link to see: [pop up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJr0b.png)

I am trying to automate this:http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth in chrome using Selenium java.
I want to insert username, passwors and then either click sign in or cancel.
But I am not able to "inspect element".

Comment: This will help you. Its an open bug as of now with selenium drivers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303422/selenium-user-prompt-of-type-promptuserandpass-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is window authentication pop-up, not javascript alert. So, in this case you need to modify Webdriver URL. (AutoIT also can be applicable. But below is the simple way to handle it.)

 say, username=admin, password=admin. Just pass the below URL:

```
driver.get("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the driver over to the `alert`:

```java
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Some text");
```

You might be able to send the `tab` key to switch from username box to password box.

Comment: how to send the tab key?

Comment: driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Some text");
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Some text");

Comment: and this is not working